# Problem with writing a table

Tags: tables, longtable

Hi everyone I'm trying do write a table but I have some problem. Could you help me in order to fix it?

[image]

This is my code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 

 \usepackage{amsbsy}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pbox}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage{tabularx} 
 \usepackage{booktabs} 
 \usepackage{multirow} 
 \usepackage{longtable} 


 \usepackage{textcomp} 

 \linespread{1.5}


 \usepackage{multicol}

 \usepackage{textcomp} 

 \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}




 \usepackage{pifont}




 \usepackage{bbding}
 \usepackage{mathtools}% superior to amsmath



 \newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }




 \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
 \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
 \fbox{%
 \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
 \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
 #2
 }%
 }%
 \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
 }




 \begin{document}



 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|}
 \hline
 S.  & P.  coll    & Let sta   & L.C.O.    & L.C.V.             \\
 \hline
 S $2.51$ $ [\text{t}] $  & A & $ 2.7 $ $ 1.9 $  & $ 6.69 $      & $                     8°13'30''$ $ 8°14'30''$          \\
 \hline
 & B & $ 3.1 $ $ 2.1 $  & $ 6.32 $      & $ 5°03'40''$ $ 5°04'50''$                \\
 \hline   

 \end{tabular}




 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `multirow` and `multicolumn`. Note that I dropped everything from the preamble which was unimportant regarding your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{S.}& P.& Let & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{L.C.}\\\cline{4-5}
&coll&sta&L.C.O.    & L.C.V.  \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{S 2.51[\text{t}]}  & \multirow{2}{*}{A} &2.7& \multirow{2}{*}{6.69}&$8^\circ13'30''$\\
&&1.9&&$8^\circ14'30''$\\
\cline{2-5}
& \multirow{2}{*}{A}&3.1&\multirow{2}{*}{6.32}&$5^\circ03'40''$               \\
&&2.1&&$5^\circ04'50''$ \\
\hline   
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to write P. coll and Let sta like my picture, but if I write "P. \\ coll" and "Let \\ sta" it doesn't work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ryuk I corrected according to your wishes ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot...last question...How can I write "S \\ 2.51 [t]" (S and 2.51 [t] written like P. coll - two different line but same cell). I'm trying to understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: You can use `\cline` to add a partial horizontal line. E.g. `\cline{2-5}` draws horizontal line only in columns 2-5. You should create two cells for S and 2.51 [t] without drawing a line between them.

Comment: Could you please write me please the exat code in order to write  "S \\ 2.51 [t]" (S and 2.51 [t] written like P. coll - two different line but same cell). I don't understand. Thanks ;)